# Exception while running tests through cassandra-unit

Tags: junit, cassandra

I keep getting this error while running junit tests in maven : com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Channel has been closed

It eventually leads to OutOfMemory exception.

I am using cassandra-unit to run an embedded cassandra cluster. After a few test cases it starts throwing the following error : 
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Channel has been closed
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:306)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:293)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:265)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.refreshSchema(ControlConnection.java:230)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager$2.run(Cluster.java:951)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1] Channel has been closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelClosed(Connection.java:566)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:60)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:60)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:493)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelClosed(FrameDecoder.java:371)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:555)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:468)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:351)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:107)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:312)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)`

I have tried to give enough memory to the process(-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m) but it doesn't help

Comment: You need to give far more detail. What are you trying to do? Can you paste the code for the test? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do a clean driver shutdown before the test suite is torn down...

Looks like a typical 'connection closed' stack trace by the driver which is expected behavior when the test is finished and the driver ('Cluster' object) has still open connections.

Try a com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster#close() call in a @After-annotated tear down method of your test case.